# Chart Question and Percentages

Tags: data-analysis

The Venn Diagram above represents the 20 students who took one or more of the 3 available art class or took no art class at all. What percent of the students took only 1 art class?

A. 10%

B. 20%

C. 30%

D. 40%

E. 50%

Comment: It is very easy where do you stuck?

Comment: @i.ozturk I'm not sure how to count the people in the diagram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Students which take only one class are placed into the non-intersecting parts of the diagram:

[image]

Adding these: $3+3+4=10$

$10/20=\%50$ takes only one class.

Comment: so the number of people who only take two activities is 7? could you also help me with this problem ? https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-4lJHUDH1P5bVNiTlpBbUhyRVk/edit

Comment: @Ben Yes that's correct. I think you can do the other question by drawing on your own (draw parallel hour lines for each person).